# $f: \mathbb{R}^{n+1}-\{0\}\rightarrow S^{n}$ via $x \mapsto\frac{x}{\|x\|}$ is continuous

Tags: metric-spaces, uniform-continuity, spheres

I'm having trouble understanding why a map $f: \mathbb{R}^{n+1}-\{0\}\rightarrow S^{n}$ ([unit $n$-sphere](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Sphere/Topology/Unit_Sphere), $n\ge 1$) via $x \mapsto\frac{x}{||x\|}$ is continuous.
Since [Unit n-Sphere under Euclidean Metric is Metric Subspace of Euclidean Real Vector Space](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Unit_n-Sphere_under_Euclidean_Metric_is_Metric_Subspace_of_Euclidean_Real_Vector_Space),
I think that continuity of $f$ can be proved by [$(\epsilon-\delta)$-definition of limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/(%CE%B5,_%CE%B4)-definition_of_limit). 
That is for every real number $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $\delta > 0$ 
such that for every $x, y \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}-\{0\}$ with $||x-y|| < \delta$, we have that 
$||\frac{x}{||x\|}- \frac{y}{||y\|}|| < \epsilon$.
How $\delta$ can be chosen?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I think you'd rather write $f$ as a composition of well-known continuous maps.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli What are they?

Comment: Norm, scalar multiplication, $\frac1t$, pairing of continuous maps...

Comment: Note that the $\epsilon$ $\delta$ definition allows your choice of $\delta$ to depend on the point $x$. The property you've stated is called uniform continuity, which is a little stronger and not true for this function.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli $f$ isn't a real-valued function. How can you define functions like $\frac1t$?

Comment: The norm is.${}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: reverse triangle inequality will be helpful.

$$ \left\Vert \frac{x}{\Vert x \Vert} - \frac{y}{\Vert y \Vert} \right\Vert \leq \frac{\Vert x-y\Vert + \vert \Vert x \Vert-\Vert y \Vert \vert}{\Vert x \Vert} \leq \frac{2}{\Vert x \Vert} \Vert x - y \Vert $$

You get the first inequality by adding and subtracting $y/\Vert x \Vert$ then applying the usual triangle inequality and doing some manipulations. The second inequality is the reverse triangle inequality. Now take $\delta < \epsilon\Vert x \Vert/2$.

Comment: I think you mean $\delta < \Vert x \Vert\epsilon / 2$?

Comment: Yes of course. I fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

To start, you may assume without loss that $\|x\| > \|y\|$. Now let $\epsilon>0$ be given then if $\|x-y\|< \delta$ where $\delta = \|y\| \epsilon$ we have; $$\left\|\frac{x}{\|x\|} - \frac{y}{\|y\|}\right\|  = \frac{1}{\|x\| \|y\|} \cdot \left\|\ x\|y\|- y\|x\| \ \right\| \leq \frac{1}{\|x\| \|y\|} \cdot \left\|\ x\|x\|- y\|x\| \ \right\|$$

$$=\frac{1}{\|x\| \|y\|} \cdot \left\|\ x\|x\|- y\|x\| \ \right\| = \frac{1}{\|x\| \|y\|} \cdot \left\|\|x\|(x-y)\| \ \right\| = \frac{1}{\|y\|} \cdot \|x-y\|< \epsilon$$